# Loading inline CSS in Android Webview problem

Tags: android, css, webview

I am developing an androind webview based application - the HTML, CSS and Javascript is built dynamically - I have done this before but have run into a insanely madding problem. when the css starts loading in webview it stops loading at the # color - The CSS build is as follows:

```
    String h1 =
            ".sexy_line{\n" +
                    "    display:block;\n" +
                    "    border:none;\n" +
                    "    color:transparent;\n" +
                    "    height:6px;\n" +
                    "    background:black;\n" +
                    "    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 450, from(#2626ff), to(#ffffff00));\n" +
                    "}\n"   +
                    ".floatBottom\n" +
                    "     {\n" +
                    "     position: absolute; \n" +
                    "     bottom: 0;\n" +
                    "     }\n";
return h1;
}
```

it literally stops loading at:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 450, from(
```

Environment:

Android: Tablet 7.1.1
Development Environment: Android Studio 3.5.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated --- Thank you

an update: i am loading the page with the following method:

```
 wv = findViewById(R.id.idWebView);            
 settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
 wv.loadData(webInterface,"text/html","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Just realized that css stops loading anytime there is a # in the CSS script.

Comment: Question, has anyone notices a webview problem in SDK Re; 29. When i went back to 25 everything seemed to work perfectly. is this a know problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was facing the same issue after I updated my target SDK.
Solved this by base64 encoding my HTML and then passing it `base64` in encoding:

```
// instructions is the HTML string   

 webView.loadData(Base64.encodeToString(instructions.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT), "text/html", "base64");
```

Please check the blue box in the documentation, here:
[WebView.loadData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

[blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OigP7.png)